# How to create a Scaling/rotating square using keypress program in java?

Tags: java

I want to create a program that has a key press events in the animation of square.

I want this kind of output:
For example i will press 'D or d' the square should rotate clockwise ,2nd.. if i will press 'A or a' the square should rotate counter-clockwise, 3rd if I will press 'S or s' the rotation should stop,4th if i will press 'Z or z' the image of the square should grow bigger, and Finally if i will press 'X or x' the the square should be smaller..

i hope you can help me guys i just need it for my assignment thanks in advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not usually the place to ask for full assignment code. In general, you need to show us some code, and ask a specific problem that you encountered and researched (searching can answer most entry coding problems faster than you can ask here).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article about rotating stuff using Graphics2D class. Hope it helps.
http://beginwithjava.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/rotating-image-with-java.html

To use the keys you need to add KeyListener to JPanel where you draw:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RotationPanel extends JPanel {
    public RotationPanel() {

        setFocusable(true);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
                if (ev.getKeyChar() == 'd') rotateRight();
                if (ev.getKeyChar() == 'a') rotateLeft();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Remember about requesting focus in the frame where you add panel :).

You have to implement rotateRight() and rotateLeft(). That shouldn't be difficult after you read the article I added the link to.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the above code of key pressed with key released . Because that wont work. I have done the same thing that enables AJAX like capability in Swing Application framework and even have build a project using the same .